# Three percentage indicators into one (or two measures) in regression moder

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, assumptions

I am working with a data set resembling the extract below:

```
MeasuerA MeasureB MeasureC Cost
10       89       1        100
5        83       2        120
30       69       1        100
20       79       1        90
25       74       1        95
15       83       2        100
5        94       1        110
4        95       1        10
10       88       2        110
6        93       1        85
7        92       1        100
```

The nature of the data set is that the two measures (*MeasureA* and *MeasureB*) are reversly proportional with some "noise" being introduced by the *MeasureC*. I'm interesting in doing a regression analysis answering on the relationship of the measures to the *Cost* variable. Naturally, when introduced to the model the measures *A* and *B* will display a high degree of multicollinearity. In effect, I can run the model with only *MeasureA* or *MeasureB*; however, I would like to make statements about both of the measures as impacting (or not) the *Cost* variable. In particular, I would like to be able to state that: *"This change in **MeasureA** and related change in **MeasureB** results in **Cost** being higher/lower"* Presently, I don't have access to any other variables than those described in the data extract. 
My question is how can I work around the multicollinearity problem? Would it be sensible to attempt to transform the measures into one "index-like" indicator reflecting the proportionality of distribution between those two variables and then introducing the generated index variable to the model? I presume that I can always run the model with only one of the measures (*A* or *B*) but I won't be able to make the statment that change in *MeasureA* and corresponding change in *MeasureB* result in this change to cost as the existence of *MeasureC* suggests that *MeasureB* is not simply *(100% - MeasureA)* as the *MeasureC* impacts the distribution in effect:
$$
100\% = MeasureA + MeasureB + MeasureC
$$